# django-ckeditor {{ form.media }} not working in html

Tags: html, django, django-ckeditor

I am trying to get ck-editor look from forms.py .
After reading docs and even on YouTube, I didn't get my desired result. 
I am sharing my different file. 
Please solve this.

> HTML FILE

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="col me-2">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ notes_form.media }}
          {{ notes_form.as_p }}
   </div>
   <div class="col-auto">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm border rounded-pill border-success float-end todo-submit" type="button">
            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

> Form.py

```
class NotesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Notes
        fields = ['description']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NotesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
```

> views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        params = {
            "notes_form": NotesForm()
        }
        return render(request, 'dashboard.html', params)
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html')
```

> output (html file)

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZQz2.png)

Comment: are you doing this locally or on a production server?

Comment: In your ``NotesForm`` you've specified fields as description ```fields = ['description']``` you can access only that attribute for eg. ```{{ notes_form.description }}``` if you want to access media than you have to add that in your fields.

Comment: Using for production server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I got the solution.

when you call `{{ notes_form.media }}`, it load script files i.e. `<script src="/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js"></script><script src="/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>`. Due to this JavaScript load first and it didn't get the textarea which appear (due to) `{{ notes_form.as_p }}` after this.

> HTML file

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="col me-2">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ notes_form.media }}
          {{ notes_form.as_p }}
   </div>
   <div class="col-auto">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm border rounded-pill border-success float-end todo-submit" type="button">
            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

> updated HTML file

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="col me-2">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ notes_form.as_p }}
          {{ notes_form.media }}
   </div>
   <div class="col-auto">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm border rounded-pill border-success float-end todo-submit" type="button">
            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```